# Stripe and Firebase: FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, npm, stripe-payments

I'm trying to setup stripe on my new Firebase app (React). I'm using the new version of Firebase (9) and the new Stripe integration, published 12 days ago:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@stripe/firestore-stripe-payments

What I'm trying to do here is to load the stripe-hosted checkout for a subscription.

This is the code:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { createCheckoutSession } from "@stripe/firestore-stripe-payments";
import { payments } from './Firebase'

export default function Stripetest(props) {


    async function checkout(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            const session = await createCheckoutSession(payments, {
                    price: "price_1JwyWZIweuKs6S3NBDjBqiiw",
            });
            window.location.assign(session.url);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
        
    }
        

    

    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={checkout}>Checkout</button>
        </>
    )
}
```

This is the Firebase.js that exports "payments":

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
import { getFirestore, collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
import { getStripePayments } from "@stripe/firestore-stripe-payments";
import { getApp } from "@firebase/app";

// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional

const firebaseApp = initializeApp({
 apiKey: "AIzaSxxxxxxxxxx",
 authDomain: "bxxxxxxxxxx6.firebaseapp.com",
 projectId: "bxxxxxxxx6",
 storageBucket: "xxxxxxxx.appspot.com",
 messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
 appId: "1:xxxxxxx",
 measurementId: "G-Kxxxxx"
});


export const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp)
export const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp)
export default firebaseApp;

const app = getApp();

export const payments = getStripePayments(app, {
 productsCollection: "products",
 customersCollection: "customers"
});
```

I've tried both "app" and "firebaseApp" in "getStripePayments(APP, {" but when I click the checkout button it's always the same error:

> FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore

Comment: Looks like you're not the only one experiencing this issue.  I recommend you add a comment to this GitHub issue as it seems to be a bug in the library: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-firebase-extensions/issues/304

Comment: Yep it was a bug. Now they have fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

I downgraded from:

```
"@stripe/firestore-stripe-payments": "0.0.4",
```

to

```
"@stripe/firestore-stripe-payments": "0.0.3",
```

in **package.json** and the bug stopped occurring and all works fine now